# Conditional method chaining in java

Tags: java

What is the best possible way to chain methods together? In my scenario, there are *four* methods. If the output of the *first* method is `true`, it has to call the *second* method.

**For Example:**

```
flag = method1();
if (flag){
  flag = method2();
}
if (flag){
  method3();
} 
// and so on for next methods ..
```

Comment: Use a nested set of conditional operators. It won't be legible but it will work.

Comment: Do you need to return `flag` after the last method has been executed?

Comment: "best" by what metric?

Answer (score 20):

Use the `&&` logical `AND` operator:

```
if (method1() && method2() && method3() && method4()) {
    ........
}
```

Java evaluates this condition from left to right.  
If any of the methods returns `false`,  then the evaluation stops, because the final result is `false` (**Short Circuit Evaluation**).

Comment: That doesn't put anything in flag.

Comment: The flag is not needed this way.

Comment: This is hacker way :) But makes code, probably, hard to read.

Comment: @Koziołek If you know what you're doing, it is not hard to read.

Comment: @forpas, "if you know" is a key. I you read code probably you want to know what author did. Better solution in this case is nested ifs `if(method1()){if(method2(){…}}`, looks bad, but is easier to understand.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this depends on side-effects being acceptable. I see this as an issue of readability and expectation; I generally do not expect boolean valued functions to perform side effects. Of course, if the methods are called something like "doTheSideEffect()", that point might be moot.

Comment: @RebeccaNelson There is nothing specific about side-effects in this case because the question is based on a how-to-do-this basis.

Comment: All the methods are in different classes , will it not be clumpsy and hard to read ,if we do it this way? Do we have any design pattern which solves this issue

Comment: @user10821509 *clumpsy* compared to what? **You** asked an alternative way, I suppose because you found clumpsy the way you were implementing this. *hard to read* why? Now you know how the `&&` operator works.

Comment: @user10821509 Thanks! and I know how && operator works.I was looking for a better and optimal solution

Comment: @user10821509 *better* isn't this than nested ifs? This is a matter of style maybe. *optimal*? I don't think that any other solution could do better than this. Equally maybe, better no.

Answer (score 7):

if `flag` is not needed somewhere later on then @forpas's answer is the way to go otherwise I'd do:

```
flag = method1() && method2() && method3() && method4()
```

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost I'd like to state that this answer is by no means more efficient than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890008/conditional-method-chaining-in-java/53890068#53890068) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890008/conditional-method-chaining-in-java/53890152#53890152) rather it's just another way in which you can accomplish the task at hand while maintaining the *short-shircuting* requirement of yours.

So first step is to create a method as such:

```
public static boolean apply(BooleanSupplier... funcs){
      return Arrays.stream(funcs).allMatch(BooleanSupplier::getAsBoolean);
}
```

This function consumes any number of functions that have the signature `() -> boolean` i.e. a supplier (a function taking no inputs and returns a boolean result).

Then you can call it as follows using a method reference:

```
if(apply(Main::method1, 
         Main::method2, 
         Main::method3, 
         Main::method4)){ ... };
```

Where `Main` is the class where the methods are defined.

or lambda:

```
if(apply(() -> method1(), 
         () -> method2(), 
         () -> method3(), 
         () -> method4())){ ... };
```

Comment: This one is likely more readable if the list is more than 3 or 4.

Answer (score 3):

To use the short circuit but keep it more readable, you can do

```
boolean flag = method1();
flag = flag && method2();
flag = flag && method3();
```

And so on. Note you can't use `flag &= methodX()` because that doesn't short circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Nested conditional operators would solve this:

```
flag = method1() ? (method2() ? method3(): false): false;
```

Comment: nice +1, you can simplify it to `flag = method1() && (method2() && method3());`. assuming `flag` is needed after the condtions then this is a good approach.

Comment: @Aomine I think that would be better answer than this

Comment: @Aomine but the conditional operator get so little respect! :)

Comment: @nicomp right, i'll post it as an answer then :). #eis sure thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&&` operator :

```
boolean flag = method1() && method2() && method3() && method4() && ...;
```

Do whatever with `flag`.

Answer (score 0):

incase the methods truth values have to be saved or other side-effects have to happen:

```html
boolean flag;
switch(1){
  case 1: flag = method1();  
          //additional code goes here

          if(!flag) break; 
  case 2: flag = method2();
          //additional code goes here

          if(!flag) break; 
     ....
  default: flag = method10();
          if(!flag) break; 
}
```

you shouldn't  want this and it's... unexpected.
but this is a readable way of adding additional statements to each code path.

otherwise: do it differently or fall back on ifs.